# Error while loading shared libraries: libmozsqlite3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: software-installation

I have installed Ubuntu today and I want to upgrade Firefox, but whenever I try to run using `./updater` , it shows me this error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libmozsqlite3.so cannot open
shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Also, the problem is not with Firefox only, but the OS itself is not allowing me to install any program. Please, tell me what am I missing?